# How can I fix warning deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char

The code is:

```
char *prefix(node)::name() const 
{ 
   return str(prefix(node)); 
}
```

The message is `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you want to return a char* or a string?

Comment: I want to return char*

Comment: What do you mean by `prefix(node)` in the first line?  Doesn't look like valid C++.

Comment: @DrewHall, it's likely that `prefix` is a macro.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get this warning is that the pointer you return points to global data that may or may not be protected as read-only, so any change to it will either crash or be reflected on each subsequent call.

If you think that it's not an issue because you don't plan to modify it, return a `const char*` instead. If you want to return a locally-modifiable string (one on which changes won't be reflected on subsequent calls to this method), either return a `std::string` or `strdup` the string (but then don't forget to `free` it by yourself). If you want to return a globally-modifiable string (one where the changes will be reflected on subsequent calls to this method), return a pointer to a global array instead of a direct string constant:

```
char *prefix(node)::name() const 
{
    static char string[] = str(prefix(node));
    return string;
}
```

This assumes that `str` is a macro returning a string constant.

The latter solution implements a warning-less state of status quo.